# Problem with publishg net core API into Azure

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have a net core 3.1 REST API and I want to publish it into Azure. I started by following this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-api-management-using-vs?view=aspnetcore-5.0

**When I added Swagger I encountered a problem with a generic error 'HTTP ERROR 550.30' after installing version 3 of the Swashbuckle.AspNetCore package. When I install the last version the API works again locally but I can not publish it into Azure because swagger could not make the swagger JSON file.
I tried many suggestions from GitHub and nothing worked!
Note: if I moved into version 3.0.0 from the library I can publish the API but end again with 'HTTP ERROR 550.30'**

Finally, I encounter today a different error even that I did not change anything on the code which is:
'Web deployment task failed. (Web Deploy cannot modify the file 'BuildingRestAPI.dll' on the destination because it is locked by an external process. In order to allow the publish operation to succeed, you may need to either restart your application to release the lock or use the AppOffline rule handler for .Net applications on your next publish attempt. Learn more at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_FILE_IN_USE. '

I will apprentice any help because I'm running of time for this assignment and I already wasted three days on this problem
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you receive the `HTTP ERROR 550.30`? Cause I thought it should be an `HTTP ERROR 500.30`.

I followed this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-api-management-using-vs?view=aspnetcore-5.0) you post and tested the code both with version 3 and latest of the `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` package. When using the latest version, my api app works well both locally and on Azure, and I could see the `Swagger.json` file through these api:

```
https://{your-website}/swagger/v1/swagger.json
https://{your-website}/swagger/index.html
```

When using the version 3.0.0, my project cannot be published because of the incompatible issue. It seems my project use high `.net core` version, which `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` package version is too low to support.

This is my `Startup.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using NLog.Extensions.Logging;

namespace TodoApi
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private readonly string swaggerBasePath = "api/app";
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddSwaggerGen();
            services.AddLogging(builder =>
            {
                builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information);
                builder.AddNLog("nlog.config");
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseSwagger();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

1. Update the `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` package version to higher, such as `5.0.0`, avoiding some unknown issue with latest version, to see if it works or not locally.
2. When it works well locally, you could publish again, and diagnostic with the logs on **kudu** if it still get error.